Expo-Sqlite: strange behaviour on unique constraint violation
I have a database schema that uses a lot of Unique constraints in non pk/fk fields, i want to use it in my expo app using the Expo-SQLite library, before that i'm making some tests with the library.
The issue is when i try to insert a row in a simple test table which violates the Unique constraint over the 'Name' field app freezes (console.log doesn't work after that, even refreshing the app), have wrapped the query in a try/catch but nothing is thrown, the Expo-SQlite methods can return a ResultErrorSet object but in this case this kind of object is not returned (works in other cases, like using select on a non-existing table).
Besides after this bug when i try to insert another row which doesn't violate the constraint the console prints a 'database locked' error, i have to restart the development server to make it work properly again.
This only happens in this case, other queries like select, insert (with no violation), and delete works properly... im completely stuck on this...
Schema:
`create table if not exists User (
    ID integer not null primary key,
    Name varchar(200),
    constraint unq_Name unique (Name)
)`

Library wrapper:
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
import {
    ResultSet,
    ResultSetError
} from 'expo-sqlite';

export class DBAPI {

    private static url: string = 'NutriDashDB.db';

    public static open() {
        return SQLite.openDatabase(this.url).
    }

    public static async close(db: SQLite.SQLiteDatabase) {
        return db.closeAsync()
    }

    public static async query(query: string, readOnly: boolean, args ? : Array < string | number > ): Promise < Array < SQLite.ResultSet | SQLite.ResultSetError > | undefined > {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            let db = this.open();
            db.execRawQuery([{
                sql: query,
                args: args || []
            }], readOnly, async (err, set) => {
                await this.close(db)
                if (err) rej(err.message)
                if (set && set[0].hasOwnProperty('error')) rej((set[0] as ResultSetError).error.message)
                res(set)
            })
        })
    }
}

HelloWorld.tsx:
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
import {
    ResultSet,
    ResultSetError
} from 'expo-sqlite';

export class DBAPI {

    private static url: string = 'NutriDashDB.db';

    public static open() {
        return SQLite.openDatabase(this.url).
    }

    public static async close(db: SQLite.SQLiteDatabase) {
        return db.closeAsync()
    }

    public static async query(query: string, readOnly: boolean, args ? : Array < string | number > ): Promise < Array < SQLite.ResultSet | SQLite.ResultSetError > | undefined > {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            let db = this.open();
            db.execRawQuery([{
                sql: query,
                args: args || []
            }], readOnly, async (err, set) => {
                await this.close(db)
                if (err) rej(err.message)
                if (set && set[0].hasOwnProperty('error')) rej((set[0] as ResultSetError).error.message)
                res(set)
            })
        })
    }
}

I've tried with another library methods like transactionAsync or executeAsync and have the same behaviour in all of them.
Im using a Pixel 4 AVD. Expo SDK version 50.0.0.
